# ISPConfig/postfix mail forward fails for one address only

Tags: postfix, mailing-list

We are running a postfix mail server under ISPConfig 3.0.5.4p8. The host machine is running Debian stretch. We have successfully set up several mail forwarding instances. However, one particular forwarding address fails. Altering the name by a single character works. So (for example), `forward@mydomain.com` fails, but `forward2@mydomain.com` succeeds. In the first case, the forward rule seems to be expanded to `forward@mail.mydomain.com`, which then is rejected. There is nowhere else in the system (as far as I can tell) where the rejected name is referenced. I have tried temporarily disabling ClamAV and amavis, to no avail.

Comment: what is the exact name of the mail address/forward that fails, and are you sure it fails or it does not reach destination. what does mail.log say ?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: it turned out to be an interaction with a quiescent installation of mailman that we were not actually using. Simply removing mailman broke things horribly, but removing references to it in postfix's config fixed things.